# Minimize the Sum of Reciprocal of Probabilities

Tags: probability-distributions, optimization, convex-optimization, stochastic-calculus

I need a probability distribution over $ n $ events such that the sum of expected values is minimized. That is, minimize

The problem is given by:

$$\begin{aligned}
\arg \min_{ {p}_{i} } & \; && \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{ {p}_{i} } \\ 
\text{subject to} & \; && \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {p}_{i} = 1
\end{aligned}$$

I guess it's a basic easy question. I would appreciate any hint.

Comment: I believe the minimum value of this sum is just $1$ where we have a single event of probability $1$. Any other combination of events would have some $p_i\lt1$ for which $1/p_i\gt1$ hence the sum would be $\gt1$.

Comment: I think there is an hidden assumption that $ \forall i, \; {p}_{i} > 0 $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's use the method of Lagrange multipliers:

$$ L=\sum_i\frac{1}{p_i}+\lambda\left(\sum_ip_i-1\right)\implies0=\frac{\partial L}{\partial p_i}=\lambda-\frac{1}{p_i^2}\implies\frac{\partial^2L}{\partial p_i^2}=\frac{2}{p_i^3}>0, $$

So it is guaranteed that the extreme point is a Minimum Point.
Moreover:

$$ 0 = \lambda - \frac{1}{ {p}_{i}^{2} } \Rightarrow {p}_{i} = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{\lambda} } $$

And from the constraint:

$$ \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{ \sqrt{\lambda} } = 1 \Rightarrow \lambda = {n}^{2} $$

Which suggests that $ {p}_{i} = \frac{1}{n} $.

Comment: Doesn't $ 0 = \lambda - \frac{1}{ {p}_{i}^{2} } $ suggests that $ {p}_{i} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}} $?

Comment: @Royi Thanks; fixed.

Comment: I also thinks that your solution only holds for the case $ {p}_{i} > 0, \; \forall i $. If we are allowed to have value of $ 0 $ (And then we need to take care of the reciprocal) then the result is different.

Comment: @Royi You can't get a smaller, or even a finite, $\sum_i\frac{1}{p_i}$ if any $p_i$ is $0$.

Comment: This is why I wrote above that I think it is hidden assumption.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an argument that tells you that the minimum value can only be  attained the $p_i$'s are equal. Suppose the minimum value is attained when $p_i=q_i, 1 \leq i \leq n$. If possible let $q_i \neq q_j$. Note that $\frac 1 {q_i} +\frac 1 {q_j} >\frac 1 {\frac {q_i+q_j} 2}+\frac 1 {\frac {q_i+q_j} 2}$. [This is simply a re-writing of the inequality $(q_i-q_j)^{2} >0]$. Thus there is a choice of $p_i$'s for which we get a value lower than the minimum. This contradiction shows that $p_i$ are all equal when the minimum is attained.

Comment: For the sake of rigor we may note that a continuous function on a compact set has a minimum, so there is indeed one choice $(p_i)$ which gives the minimum value.

Comment: thanks for the nice proof! The definition of $q_i$ is not clear, but the idea is very clear.

Comment: @Parham I used $(q_i)$ for the choice of $(p_i)$ which minimzes $\sum \frac 1 {p_i}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The set is not compact (it's not closed), no ?

Comment: For fixed $n$ the collection of all $(p_1,p_2,...,p_n)$ with $p_i >0$  and $\sum p_i=1$ is not closed. However we are minimizing $\sum \frac 1 {p_i}$ and it is easy to see that this function attains its minimum.